# Mounting a host directory with Docker Compose in Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm using Docker for Windows on WSL2. When I do this on a Dockerfile, the contents of my directory in the host are copied correctly to the new image after building:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
```

However, this docker compose YAML doesn't mount the same directory in the same location:

```yaml
version: "2.0"

services:
  node:
    image: node
    user: node
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    tty: true
```

After accessing the container, I'm not able to see the contents on my host directory in it. I've also tried with the full host path, but it didn't work.

When I run `docker inspect` on my container, I see this, which contains the correct information:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/mnt/c/Users/my-user/my-dir",
                "Destination": "/home/node/app",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand very well. Are you trying to have the same you're copying to /app to /home/node/app ?

Comment: @mulg0r I ended up creating the Dockerfile and copying the content because I couldn't make the volume work. Ideally, I'd like to use Docker Compose with the mounted volume in sync with my host directory, instead of the Dockerfile solution by copying the contents.

Comment: Ok, but I see that you're not mounting volume to /app dir, but /home/node/app dir. Is that correct?

Comment: @mulg0r Yes, neither of those paths work.